# I am having 2 tables with 3 columns each and I want to get the value without null considering null may be present in any columns and rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the output of 2 tables by removing the NULL

Emp Table

```
id     name   dept
1      Null    EE                 
2      Ravi    Null 
NULL   Mani    CSE
```

Stud Table

```
id name  dept       
1  Manju NULL       
2  NULL  ECE        
3  Mani  CSE
```

Output

```
id name dept
1  Manju EE 
2  Ravi  ECE
3  Mani  CSE
```

Comment: Are `name, dept` always unique? Is it possible there would be `2 Ravi Null` and also `Null Ravi XX`?

Comment: *All* columns may be null? This is literally not a relational table.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Why do you have the same information in two different tables, but with different null values?

Comment: Can more than one column be null for a row?

Comment: @BillKarwin Why is that not a relational table?

Comment: @nicomp, A relational table must have a candidate key, i.e. a subset of columns that are unique and non-null.

Comment: @BillKarwin So an RDBMS can store a table that's not relational?

Comment: @nicomp, Yes, but if you make your table's candidate key nullable, you won't be able to rely on its uniqueness, and therefore you can't make a condition to select an individual row. Technically many RDBMS products allow this, but it's a bad design.

Comment: @BillKarwin I didn't see the NULL value in the id field. Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using left join and coalesce() function

```
    select a.id, coalesce(a.name,b.name) as name, coalesce(a.dept,b.dept)
    from stud a left join emp b
    on a.id=b.id
```

Comment: This would not cover the case of a NULL id, as in the 3rd row.

Comment: for this case, I considered the stud table as left table @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: If there are two `Emp` with null ID, you only get one row in the result. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6726eea8eefc7a21bd2462e5be1c0142

Comment: This produces the desired output for the example input shown, it's not clear how well it generalizes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your ID is nullable, from what I can see it is the primary key of you table. But if you want to select all data removing the NULL. Just add a condition.
For example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(e.name, s.name) name,
       COALESCE(e.dept, s.dept) dept
  FROM emp e
     LEFT JOIN stud s
        ON s.id = e.id
```

But honestly, you should check the way you created your database. As someone commented, this is not a relational table.

Comment: This doesn't get anything like the desired output: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1190e86d1531856a85415011f9345be

Comment: He doesn't want to remove the rows with null ID, he wants to replace the null values with the corresponding value from the other table.

Comment: Just add a COALESCE them, ex: COALESCE (e.name, d.name) name

Comment: Now it's the same as fa06's answer, except it's missing the ID column.

Comment: Yep, about the Id,  in the third column is null, but the other columns aren't. That won't happen in a normal table. The problem is elsewhere, just saying.

Comment: Obviously this isn't a "normal" table.